# How to get the privileges assigned to only materialized view in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Looking for a query that will give me privileges assigned to only materialized view. I tried searching the record in `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` and it shows the table privileges (created during materialized view creation) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Join dba_tab_privs to dba_objects or dba_mviews and filter out what you don't want.

Either:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM dba_tab_privs p,
       dba_mviews m
 WHERE p.owner = m.owner
   AND p.table_name = m.mview_name
```

or:

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM dba_tab_privs p,
         dba_objects o
   WHERE p.owner = o.owner
     AND p.table_name = o.object_name
     AND o.object_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
```

Comment: DBA_TAB_PRIVS always shows the type as TABLE even it is Materialized VIEW

Comment: You have to join that to dba_objects or dba_mviews. Edited my response with example.

Comment: It lists the privilges for the table as well.. Like INSERT, UPDATE

Comment: What are you hoping to see?

Comment: You can GRANT ALL ON <MVIEW_NAME> TO <USER> and see that the INSERT AND UPDATE privileges are listed when you run the query in the answer

Comment: When you do that, you are granting access to the table that the mview code maintains, not to the mview. You don't grant privs to mview code itself. Just to the table.  Are you trying to see who has privs to refresh the mview? If so, it's either the mview owner or an account with the "alter any materialized view" system priv, which you can see in dba_sys_privs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251585/discussion-between-anupam-k-and-paul-w).